# Meaning of inertial frames in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, inertial-frames, observers

In quantum mechanics where it is difficult to speak about the precise position and momentum of a particle for a macroscopic observer, does it still make sense to speak of inertial frames or even rest frames?

Comment: The position of the origin of a frame is not an operator and not something you measure.

Comment: What does the position of the origin of a frame have to do with it? You could define a rest frame, as suggested by the answer below, as a system where the expectation of the momentum is zero. Might be feasible, albeit trivial, if the space is compact.

Comment: Sorry for being thick I simply do not understand your issue.  Maybe you have a reference where this could come up?  What pair of observables are you trying to measure *simultaneously* and how does this related to a reference frame.

Comment: My question is no more than how can "inertial/rest frames" be given some sense in QM since indeed it doesn't make sense to measure coordinates in QM. The given answer is imo a nice way to define these frames in the framework of QM.

Comment: what do you mean it doesn’t make sense to measure coordinates in QM?  We measure $\langle x\rangle, \langle x^2\rangle$, etc all the time…

Comment: True, I should rephrase it: it is difficult to speak of a (macroscopic) observer 'moving at the same speed as the particle', which in classical mechanics would be the rest frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not an expert on this topic but I would try to give a naively sensible answer.

- At least for a limited class of systems who admit a large action classical-limit, there is a sense in which we can give meaning to the concept of inertial frames in quantum mechanics using the insight from Ehrenfest theorem that the equations of motion for expectation values of Hermitian observables are isomorphic to classical equations of motion for the corresponding canonical quantities.

  - Namely, inertial frames are those in which free particles evolve according to such laws that produce $\frac{d}{dt}{\langle p\rangle}=0$.
- As to the definition of rest-frame, the only meaningful definition ought to be that the frame in which the system is in a momentum-eigenstate with the eigenvalue $0$ is the rest-frame of the said system.

  - However, as one can imagine, it is not guaranteed that one can always find a rest-frame for a given system because a given system need not be in its momentum-eigenstate (in fact, it is guaranteed for most systems that this would never happen because the momentum-eigenstates for most systems are non-normalizable and thus, physically unrealizable).

I admit that this discussion does not address the question of what physical configuration would realize an inertial observer in the way one imagines such a system in relativity (i.e., an imagined grid of clocks and rulers).

Comment: Thank you, Ehrenfest's theorem does indeed give some sense of inertial frame, although as you also point out rest frame remains a complicated concept.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to look at it. Let us assume a quantum system $\mathcal O$ whose pure state is denoted by the ray $[\Psi]$. The fundamental assumption of implementing any symmetry (and in particular the Galilean symmetry) in Quantum Mechanics is that there are two **macroscopic** observers $O$ and $\bar{O}$, so that each of them has its own version of $[\Psi]$. They define what is known as Galilean/inertial reference frames which should be familiar from Galilean/special relativity. This is the starting point of any symmetry (typically known as the Weyl-Wigner approach to Quantum Physics = "Gruppenpest") analysis of Quantum Mechanics. Replace Galilean with Lorentzian and you have the fundamentals of Relativistic Quantum Field Theory, chapter 2 of the 1st volume of Weinberg's QFT text.

The thing about these macroscopic observers is that their kinematics is well known and the "Heisenberg uncertainty" does not really apply to them. Why? Well, let us say that there is a small uncertainty in the position and momentum of the observers and that $\delta x \cdot \delta p \approx \hbar $. But for Galilean/Lorenzian frames we have a macroscopic speed $v$ which connects $O$ and $\bar{O}$ and then $\delta v =\frac{\delta p}{M_{\text{OBSERVER}}}$. The observer's mass can be taken arbitrarily high so that $\delta v$ is literally $0$. This argument is also used by Fonda and Ghirardi in their famous [text](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0824712137).

So it always makes sense to have $[\Psi] ({x_{O},v_{O},t})$ and $[\Psi] ({x_{\bar{O}},v_{\bar{O}},t})$ and $x_{O} = x_{\bar{O}} + v_{O\rightarrow \bar{O}} t$, for example.

Comment: +1: This is a nice way to look at it and as I mentioned in my answer, I specifically didn't address it, so thanks for your answer. I would mention that in close correspondence with the classical expectation that an inertial observer ought to be free, the relation $v=p/m$ only works in quantum mechanics for free systems.

Comment: Thank you for the additional answer: am I right in interpreting your answer as an explanation of the concept of inertial frame between macroscopic observers both measuring a microscopic system, whereas @DvijD.C.'s answer offers a definition of the concept of inertial frame between the macroscopic (observer) and the microscopic (what is being observed)?

Comment: @FridoRolloos. Inertial frames are all considered from the observer's point of view. The observers define reference frames in QM and relativity.

Comment: Not entirely clear to me what all this means as in classical mechanics observers can be of any size whereas in QM size matters and maybe not all observers are equal. In any case I will need to digest it and try to grasp the meaning of this.